Tao's blog on the Nullstellensatz
In Tao's blog on the Nullstellensatz, he mentions that

The presence of the exponent $r$ in [the Strong Nullstellensatz] is a little annoying; to get rid of it, one need to generalise an algebraic variety to that of a scheme.

Here, he is referring to the exponent $r$ in the strong Nullstellensatz for which, (choosing $P_{1},\ldots,P_{m},R\in k[x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}]$), there exist $Q_{1},\ldots,Q_{m}\in k[x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}]$ such that:
$$\sum_{i\le m}Q_{i}(\textbf{x})P_{i}(\textbf{x})=R(\textbf{x})^{r}$$
when there doesn't exist a $\textbf{t}\in k^{n}$ where for all $i$:
$P_{i}(\textbf{t})=0$, and for which $R(\textbf{t})\neq 0$.
I have tried researching to see if a result that manages to remove this exponent for some (non-trivial) class of polynomials has been proven, and have found nothing.

Hi, please consider making your question easier to read by providing a link to Tao’s post, and by making the entire question as self-contained as possible, in particular by defining the relevant notation. Ideally, a reader should be able to understand exactly what you’re asking without checking Tao’s blog.

@Aphelli I have added context.

This is improved, but can you also include the definitions/properties/context of the $P_i,Q_i,R$?

Are you familiar with the version of the Strong Nulstellensatz statement using ideals? (That $I(Z(J)) = \sqrt{J}$ for any ideal $J \subset k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$. )

Yes I am familiar.

I’ll delete my answer for now since I see that it misses something in your question. Sorry about that; I’ll revive it if I fix it.

I'm going to give an answer that's very similar to Daniel's deleted answer, but which I hope makes the connection to your question a bit clearer. I'm not an algebraic geometer, and I'm not Terry Tao, so I hope I haven't misrepresented the way algebraic geometers and/or Tao would think about this issue! Corrections welcome.
I believe that Tao's comment refers to the fact that in classical algebraic geometry, closed sets in the Zariski topology correspond to radical ideals, while in the world of affine schemes, closed subschemes correspond to arbitrary ideals.
Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $P_1,\dots,P_m\in k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$. Let $I = (P_1,\dots,P_m)$.
We can rephrase the strong Nullstellensatz as follows: $R\in k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ vanishes on $V(I)$ if and only if $R\in \sqrt{I}$, i.e., there exist $r\in \mathbb{N}$ and $Q_1,\dots,Q_m\in k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^m Q_iP_i = R^r$.
Here "$R$ vanishes on $V(I)$" means that for all $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in V(I)\subseteq k^n$, $R(a_1,\dots,a_n) = 0$.
On the other hand, we have a similar-looking statement in the world of schemes, but without the exponent $r$: $R\in k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ vanishes on the closed subscheme $\mathrm{Spec}(k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I)$ if and only if $R\in I$, i.e., there exist  $Q_1,\dots,Q_m\in k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^m Q_iP_i = R$.
Here "vanishes on" has a more subtle meaning. The rings $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I$ are the coordinate rings of the schemes $\mathbb{A}^n_k = \mathrm{Spec}(k[x_1,\dots,x_n])$ and $S = \mathrm{Spec}(k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I)$. The inclusion $S\hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^n_k$ induces a "restriction" map of coordinate rings $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]\to k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I$ which in this case is just the quotient map mod $I$. We say a function in the coordinate ring of $\mathbb{A}^n_k$ vanishes on $S$ if and only if it restricts to the zero function in the coordinate ring of $S$. Clearly, this happens if and only if the function is in the ideal $I$.
Note that the scheme-theoretic version of the "strong Nullstellensatz" then follows directly from the definition of vanishing on a closed subscheme. There's nothing to prove, and we didn't even need to assume that $k$ was algebraically closed, or even a field! The extra content of the classical strong Nullstellensatz is that it only requires us to check for vanishing by evaluating on the closed points, rather than looking at coordinate rings. To do this, we need to strengthen the hypothesis (by assuming $k$ is an algebraically closed field) and weaken the conclusion (by adding the exponent).
As an explicit example, let $m = n = 1$, $P = x^2$ and $R = x$. Classically, $V(I) = V(x^2) = \{0\}$, a single point. $R$ vanishes on $V(I)$, but $R\notin I = (x^2)$. We only have $R\in \sqrt{I}$, witnessed by $R^2\in I$.
In the world of schemes, the closed subscheme of $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ defined by $x^2$ is $S = \mathrm{Spec}(k[x]/(x^2))$, which is not a "single point" but rather a "fat point". As a topological space, it only has one point (corresponding to the prime ideal $p = (x)$), but its coordinate ring captures some additional information. Now the function $R = x$ does indeed vanish when evaluated at the unique point of $S$ (meaning that it maps to $0$ in the quotient ring $(k[x]/(x^2))/p$), but it does not vanish on the closed subscheme $\mathrm{Spec}(k[x]/(x^2))$, since $x + (x^2)\neq 0$ in the coordinate ring $k[x]/(x^2)$.

You’re probably right about what Tao meant. Disappointing that it wasn’t something non-trivial. Thanks for your answer.
